# Why ContactsApp.getContacts ByEmailAdress('someemail@email.com') returns [Contact] using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

Although everything now runs, I only see logged [Contact], as it's returning an array. No documentation of how to get the email besides `ContactsApp.getContacts ByEmailAdress('someemail@email.com')`, though.

Thanks for any clarification.

Antonio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the official document of `getContactsByEmailAddress(query)` is seen, the returned value is `Contact[]`. Unfortunately, although I cannot see your actual script for retrieving `[Contact]`, I guessed that you might see the returned value with `Logger.log`. If my understanding is correct, `Logger.log(ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress("### email address ###"))` show `[Contact]` in the log.

I thought that this might be the answer for `Why ContactsApp.getContacts ByEmailAdress('someemail@email.com') returns [Contact] using Google Apps Script?`.

If you want to retrieve the other data from the contact, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const res = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress("### email address ###");
// Logger.log(res) // In this case, `[Contact]` and `[Contact, Contact,,,]` can be seen.
const name = res.map(e => e.getFullName());
Logger.log(name) // In this case, as a sample, the full name is retrieved from the retrieved contact object.
```

#### Reference:

- [getContactsByEmailAddress(query)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactsbyemailaddressquery)

Comment: It did point me to the right direction. Thank you! Ended up using: ```var emailResp = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(email);
 var emails= emailResp[0].getEmails();
 var emailAddress = String(contactEmail.map(e => e.getAddress()));```

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.